# Linux as a host with multiple Windows XP virtual machines

Tags: windows, linux, virtual-machine, linux-distributions

I am tierd or how my computer slows down... no matter what I do eventually it gets slower. I think I need a new system, a new way of doing things.

Recently, for an unrelated matter I have been experimenting with virutal machines with vmware. I came up with the idea of running a linux on my box with a couple of xp or win 7 virual machines meaning I can keep things contained and easily make a new copy of a clean version.

- Does anyone have any experience with
  such a system?
- Anyone have a better approach -
  please no fan boys suggesting I just 
  use linux or mac
- What distro would make a good host - 
  not I have next to no experience with
  linux
- What would be the disadvantages?

Comment: The disadvantages is poor video performance.  If you want use your computer for playing games then this won't work.  If you are talking about office style apps then VMs work great.

Comment: I would look at something that lets you get as close to the metal as you can with your VMs, so look into Xen.

Comment: I don't play a lot of games... but I do on occasion... so maybe I should have windows as a host system too.... or have a gaming partition with only windows on.. :S

Answer (score 0):

Look into VMware ESXi for hosting/managing your VMs. This is more or less like creating your own cloud system. 
Another thing to look into would be VirtualBox on Ubuntu/Debian

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but even in a VM, your windows machine will eventually slow down. There is simply no way around that... its Windows...

A VERY easy to 'solve' this problem is to do the following:
Back up you data. (always a must before you reformat/install)
Format you HD and re-install windows.
Apply all patches and your 'basic' programs.
Restore your personal Data.
Create an IMAGE (either using Ghost or even `dd` from a linux live cd) of your harddrive on another hard drive.

When you use your new system, ALWAYS store your personal data on either an external or in your user profile (makes it easy to do very quick backups).

When you system is starting to slow down, backup your personal data (having it on another external drive will allow you to 'bypass' this step).
After you back up, use your disc image to do a 'clean install'. Meaning, within a few mins (or mayb 1 hr... go have lunch) your system will be back up to where you imaged it. Programs installed and patches applied...

This is the fastest way and easiest way to get your system to be 'fresh' really quickly. I do this every 3-4 months with my XP system (never needed to w/ my Fedora btw...) and it works miracles!

Comment: 3-4 months?! What do you do to make your systems so slow? As long as I keep a good watch on what I am installing, and make sure the HDD is not too full my system doesn't slow down.

Comment: thats just the thing, i don't give my system time to get slow. It is such a painless process that its more of a why not instead of a must. I have found that my systems usually take between 6-7 (I'm talking windows here) to slow down (even a little which is not ok w/ me). I keep all of my personal stuff on a separate external HD so when I feel like re-imaging my computer, there is no need to backup. I just load my favorite livecd at the moment, and `dd` the image back to my HD. Boom... I'm back to a full clean install. Since I've done this so many times, my install is EXACTLY how I want it...

Answer (score 0):

Over time something called "software bloat" will result in a slower system. Programs that used to use less computer resources will use more. For example; firefox five years ago used *far* less resources than the newest version, because the average computer at the time had less resources to offer. The solution to this problem from a users perspective is to upgrade your computer, uninstall some programs, or get a new computer all together.

Linux appears to be less effected by software bloat in my experience. I can run a modern linux distro on a computer that won't even run Windows XP.